# Chartjs scales.xAxis: Property 'title' does not exist on type '_DeepPartialObject

Tags: chart.js

I have upgraded from chartjs `v2.8.0` to `4.2.1`, and I am trying to set the legend title in a line chart, however I am getting this VS Code error:

[image]

However if I look at the object, `title` certainly seems to be there...

[image]

Any ideas why I am getting this type error, or alternatively how to set the legend text (dynamically)?

### Update 1

As extra information, here is how I set up my chart (in an Angular component):

```
/**
   * Create the chart and empty data object
   */
  private createChart(): void {
    if (this.chart !== undefined) {
      return;
    }

    Chart.register(LineController, PointElement, Tooltip, Legend, TimeScale, LinearScale, CategoryScale, LinearScale, LineElement);

    this.chartData = {
      datasets: [{
        fill: false, // shading under the line
        data: []
      }]
    };

    const options: ChartOptions = {
      plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
        labels: {
          padding: 10
        }
      }
    },
      elements: {
        line: {
          borderColor: this.lineColour // line colour
        }
      },
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      scales: {
        x: {
          ticks: {
            source: 'auto',
            maxRotation: 60,
            minRotation: 60,
            autoSkip: true,
          },

          grid: {
            color: this.gridLinesColor
          },

          //label: { labelString: '', display: true },

          type: 'time',
          display: true,
          position: 'bottom',
          time: {
            unit: 'minute',
            displayFormats: {
              minute: this.runtimeStatusService.getCacheTimePattern()
            }
          }
        },
        y: 
          {
            
            min: 0,            
            grid: {
              color: this.gridLinesColor,
            },            
          }
        
      }
    };

    this.chart = new Chart(this.chartRef.nativeElement, {
      type: 'line',
      data: this.chartData,
      options
    });
  }
```

And this is how I use to be able to set the x Axis legend text (in v2):

```
this.chart.config.options.scales.xAxes[0].scaleLabel.labelString = legendText;
```

And it use to show up like this:

[image]

So I just want to do the same in v4.

Answer (score 0):

I found I could do what I was after by now adding a chart **title**.

First I add title to the register..

```
Chart.register(LineController, PointElement, Tooltip, Legend, Title /* <-- add this **/, TimeScale, LinearScale, CategoryScale, LinearScale, LineElement);
```

Next I add the title to the plugings...

```
const options: ChartOptions = {
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false,  <---- HIDE THIS
      position: 'bottom',
      labels: {
        padding: 10,            
      }
    },
    title: {
      display: true,     <---- SHOW THIS
      position: 'bottom',
      text: ''
    },        
},
```

And now I can set the title at runtime...

```
this.chart.config.options.plugins.title.text = 'hello';
```

In my case, this is all I am after...

[image]